# Palindrome Generation in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I need help to write a program that generates palindrome.I managed to make reverse the string but I couldn't combine original string and reverse string together. When I write abc i need to get abccba or when I write hello I need to get helloolleh. Now I only get cba or olleh. Can someone help me with this problem?

```
.data
msg1: .asciiz "Enter the length of your input: "
msg2: .asciiz "Enter your input: "
msg3: .asciiz "Output of the program is: "

output: .space 256 # will store the output palindrome

.text
la $a0,msg1
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall
move $s1,$v0 # $s1 has the length of the string



la $a0,msg2
li $v0,4
syscall


li $a1,1024
li $v0,8
syscall
move $s0,$a0 # $s0 has the starting address of the string

#
# YOUR CODE GOES HERE(You can use additional labels at the end)
#


move $a3,$s0
move $a1,$s1




add $a3,$a3,$a1
la $a2, output($zero)
jal reverse 



la $a0,msg3
li $v0,4
syscall




la $a0,output($zero)
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall


reverse:
    # $a0 - address of string to reverse
    # a1 - length of the string
    # a2 - address of string where to store the reverse
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    bltz $a1, reverse_end
    lb $t0, 0($a3)
    subi $a1, $a1, 1
    subi $a3, $a3, 1
    sb $t0, 0($a2)
    addi $a2, $a2, 1
    jal reverse
reverse_end:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

Edit:Also this is the C++ implementation  of palindrome generation.

**C++ Implementation of the Recursive Algorithm for Palindrome Generation**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string palindrom(string input, int rem_length)
{

  if(rem_length!=0)
  {
    input=input.substr(0,1)+palindrom(input.substr(1,input.length()-1), \\
                                      rem_length-1)+input.substr(0,1);
  }
  return input;
}

int main()
{
  string input;
  cin >> input;

  input = palindrom(input, input.length());

  cout << input<< endl;

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need just to copy the input string first to the `output` string and when you pass the `output` array to the `reverse` function you need to advance the pointer by the input string length (passing `output + strlen(input)`) so the reversed string will be written right next to it.

Also I think you should use a buffer for the input. Also take care of the `'\n'` char at the end of the input string since it will be there.

With these in mind I changed you code to this

```
.data
msg1: .asciiz "Enter the length of your input: "
msg2: .asciiz "Enter your input: "
msg3: .asciiz "Output of the program is: "

input: .space 128
output: .space 256 # will store the output palindrome

.text
la $a0,msg1
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall
move $s1,$v0 # $s1 has the length of the string

la $a0,msg2
li $v0,4
syscall

move $a1, $1
la $a0, input
li $v0,8
syscall
move $s0,$a0 # $s0 has the starting address of the string

#
# YOUR CODE GOES HERE(You can use additional labels at the end)
#
move $a3,$s0 # a3 = (char *)input
move $a1,$s1 # a1 = strlen(input)


# replacing the read in new line char with 0
la $t4, input
add $t4, $t4, $a1
sb $zero, ($t4)

# copy the string to the resulting string
move $t0, $s1 # i = strlen(input)
move $t1, $s0
la $t3, output

copy_loop:
beq $t0, $zero, copy_end # i != 0
lb $t2, ($t1) 
sb $t2, ($t3) # *output = *input
addi $t1, $t1, 1 # advancing the input ptr
addi $t3, $t3, 1 # advancing the output ptr
subi $t0, $t0, 1 # i--
b copy_loop

copy_end:

add $a3,$a3,$a1 # a3 = &input[strlen(input)]
subi $a3,$a3,1 # subtracting one since the last input char is at input[strlen(input)-1]
la $a2, output
add $a2, $a2, $a1 # passing the address of output advanced by the input length
jal reverse 

la $a0,msg3
li $v0,4
syscall

la $a0,output($zero)
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall

reverse:
    # $a0 - address of string to reverse
    # a1 - length of the string
    # a2 - address of string where to store the reverse
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    bltz $a1, reverse_end
    lb $t0, 0($a3)
    subi $a1, $a1, 1
    subi $a3, $a3, 1
    sb $t0, 0($a2)
    addi $a2, $a2, 1
    jal reverse
reverse_end:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

Which seems to work for your examples in MARS 4.5 MIPS simulator.

It is very likely that this code could be done in a more optimal way, but still it seems to get the job done.

**EDIT** Idea: Save the input to the output string that way the copy is not needed, therefore the code can be reduced to this (only relevant part)

```
move $a1, $1
la $a0, output # !! using the output buffer for the input
li $v0,8
syscall
move $s0,$a0 # $s0 has the starting address of the string

#
# YOUR CODE GOES HERE(You can use additional labels at the end)
#
move $a3,$s0 # a3 = (char *)input
move $a1,$s1 # a1 = strlen(input)

# the whole copy thing deleted and don't need to be bothered by the new
# lines, it will be overwritten with the reversed string anyway

add $a3,$a3,$a1 # a3 = &input[strlen(input)]
subi $a3,$a3,1 # subtracting one since the last input char is at input[strlen(input)-1]
la $a2, output
add $a2, $a2, $a1 # passing the address of output advanced by the input length
jal reverse
```

Comment: @cvsrt Glad if it helped. See the edit I made. Make the added code way smaller.

Comment: *It is very likely that this code could be done in a more optimal way* OMFG yes.  Especially if you don't have to make it recursive!!  In-place array reversal is one of the least natural things to do recursively.  Since `read` gives you the length, you can get a pointer to the end of the user input with a couple instructions.  (And you already have the start address in a reg = end address for looping backwards).  So loop a read pointer backwards and a write pointer forward from the end of the string, doing a copy-and-reverse.  This takes one simple lbu / sb loop if you only go char-at-a-time.